# Why isn't this label updated when I use the tkinter config option?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pycharm, widget

I want to update this label, so I used the `answer_label.config` option, but it does not work for some.

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)


exit_button = tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command = root.destroy)
exit_button.place(x=1506, y=0)


def answer():
    global main_entry
    answer_label.config(main_entry)

frame = tk.Frame(root)
main_entry = tk.Entry(frame, width=100)
main_entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
go_button = tk.Button(frame, text='Go!', width=85, command = answer)
go_button.grid(row=1, column=0)
answer_label = tk.Label(text = "Hey").pack()
frame.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor='center')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

While using the config function, you have to mention what is it that you want to change.
try:-
`answer_label.config(text="Text that you want to be displayed")`

Also you have not fetched the value from the Entry widget: For that, you can use:
`answer_label.config(text=main_entry.get())`

Full code will look like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)


exit_button = tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command = root.destroy)
exit_button.place(x=1506, y=0)


def answer():
    answer_label.config(text=main_entry.get())

frame = tk.Frame(root)
main_entry = tk.Entry(frame, width=100)
main_entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
go_button = tk.Button(frame, text='Go!', width=85, command = answer)
go_button.grid(row=1, column=0)
answer_label = tk.Label(text = "Hey")
answer_label.pack()
frame.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor='center')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are not wrong here, you can remove that uncertainty in your answer. Also make a note to remove `global` as its useless there.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: can you show me how that will look like in my full code plz?

Comment: check it out now. I have updated the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This code works. It configures the label to change the text. I don't know what you are trying to achieve with the config(main_entry).

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)


exit_button = tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command = root.destroy)
exit_button.place(x=1506, y=0)


def answer():
    global main_entry, answer_label
    answer_label.config(text="hi")

frame = tk.Frame(root)
main_entry = tk.Entry(frame, width=100)
main_entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
go_button = tk.Button(frame, text='Go!', width=85, command = answer)
go_button.grid(row=1, column=0)
answer_label = tk.Label(text = "Hey")
answer_label.pack()
frame.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor='center')

root.mainloop()
```