# Why isn't my label configuring correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm

I want this label to configure into the text entry after the user enters the text and hits go but the label isn't configuring.

I want the label that says "Hello!" to change into whatever is put in the main entry. I'm looking for an answer written in full code instead of one fixed line.

Here's my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)


exit_button = tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command = root.destroy)
exit_button.place(x=1506, y=0)

def answer():
    answer_label.config(text=main_entry.get())
entry_frame = tk.Frame(root)
main_entry = tk.Entry(entry_frame, width=100)
main_entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
go_button = tk.Button(entry_frame, text= 'Go!', width=85, command= answer)
go_button.grid(row=1, column=0)
answer_label = tk.Label(text = "Hello!").pack()
entry_frame.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor='center')


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `answer_label = tk.Label(text = "Hello!").pack()` -> `answer_label = tk.Label(text = "Hello!")  \n answer_label.pack()` in two different lines

Comment: Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66919807/12198502) answer had already your question. Only if you had paid enough attention you would have got the answer.

Comment: @JacksonPro he didn't help me with that i really wanted but the guy who answered below here did so no problem

Comment: Ok my bad, But the solution did lie in that answer. Also, you don't need to pass the label as the below answer suggests. Just writing it in two different lines is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Split `tk.Label` and `pack()`.

2.Pass the lable.

```
  import tkinter as tk
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    
    
    exit_button = tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command = root.destroy)
    exit_button.place(x=1506, y=0)
    
    def answer(answer_label):
        answer_label.config(text=main_entry.get())
    entry_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    main_entry = tk.Entry(entry_frame, width=100)
    main_entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
    answer_label = tk.Label(text = "Hello!")
    answer_label.pack()
    go_button = tk.Button(entry_frame, text= 'Go!', width=85, command=lambda: answer(answer_label))
    go_button.grid(row=1, column=0)
    entry_frame.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor='center')
    
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: how can I make the code to configure the label based on what the user says, for example, if the user says hey and hits go I want to make the label say "hey(whatever he put then a colon): Hi!". Can you send an example code of what under the "answer" function?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to achieve but you can check in your ```answer``` fuction for any input/use case.. ```def answer(answer_label):
                         answer_label.config(text=f'{main_entry.get()}:Hi!')```